Getting a URL to open in a new window (merging from a field in a database)
I have a membership directory that is powered by our membership database.
https://membercentral.icri.org/membership/org-member-directory
I am searching the company Freyssinet for the example
This directory uses HTML code and other code I am not sure of...but we are having a problem where it isn't opening the website merge field in a new window properly. It keeps pulling the stem of our member portal site.
If you search and then click on the record for Freyssinet Inc. - USA and the Contact Info tab in the result, there is a website link at the bottom.
Instead of pulling the website www.FreyssinetUSA.com it is pulling the link as https://membercentral.icri.org/www.FreyssinetUSA.com - this is not correct.
Below is the coding for this area of the directory. Any ideas as to what is wrong with the code or what I can try to add? We have been working on this for over 2 months with our database developers and they cannot figure it out.
<section class="org-website">
{% if organization.website %}  
<h6>Website:</h6>
<p><a href="{{organization.website}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{organization.website}}</a></p>
{% endif %}
</section>
</div>
</div>

Screenshot of the area of directory with the weird link
I tried to use the window.open() method and that did not work either.
I also tried creating a button with a click function and the button shows up, but it isn't clickable.
